# Use ajax to post form data to .net core mvc model-less controller action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have thirty-something forms that I am designing to allow partially completed forms to be saved in a table until the user returns to the form.  I currently have it working, but I have to create Insert and Update models for each form because of having to utilize a model for each to make ajax submit the data properly.  I know there has to be a way to make the controller actions generic so they will save data for any form.  The table I save into has five fields.  They are:
UserId int,
ParticipantActivityId int,
JsonData nvarchar(max),
DateStored datetime,
FormName nvarchar(50)

Example forms/views are:

```
<div>
   <form asp-action="Form1Add" id="form1Add">
     <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
     <input asp-for="Input1" />
     <input asp-for="Input2" />
     <input asp-for="Input3" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit form 1" class="btn btn-primary" />
   </form>
</div>
@section Scripts{
  @{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SpeScripts");
  }
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        autosave();
        return "Your entries will save.";
    }

    window.setInterval(autosave, 60000);

    function saveforlater() {
        autosave();
        alert("Your entries for this form have been saved.")
    }

    function autosave() {
        var form = $('#form1Add');
        var formName = "FORM1Add";
        var id = $('#Id').val();
        var json = form.serialize();
        var exists = checkRecords(id, formName, json);
    }
</script>
}
```

Another but imagine there being 30.

```
<div>
   <form asp-action="Form2Add" id="form2Add">
     <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
     <input asp-for="Input1" />
     <input asp-for="Input2" />
     <input asp-for="Input3" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit form 1" class="btn btn-primary" />
   </form>
</div>
    @section Scripts{
  @{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_SpeScripts");
  }
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        autosave();
        return "Your entries will save.";
    }

    window.setInterval(autosave, 60000);

    function saveforlater() {
        autosave();
        alert("Your entries for this form have been saved.")
    }

    function autosave() {
        var form = $('#form2Add');
        var formName = "FORM2Add";
        var id = $('#Id').val();
        var json = form.serialize();
        var exists = checkRecords(id, formName, json);
    }
</script>
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkRecords(activityID, formName, json) {
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/TempData/CheckRecord/" + activityID + "/" + formName,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.message == true) {
            //updateRecord(activityID, formName, json);
            updateRecord2(activityID, formName, json);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //saveRecord(activityID, formName, json);
            saveRecord2(activityID, formName, json);
            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        return false;
    }
});
}
function saveRecord2(activityId, formName, json) {
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/TempData/Insert" + "/" + activityId + "/" + formName + "/",
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.message);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
}
function updateRecord2(activityId, formName, json) {
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/TempData/Update" + "/" + activityId + "/" + formName + "/",
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(response.status + "--" + response.message);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
}
```

My Attempt at a generic controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{id?}/{formName?}/{formModel?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Insert(int id, string formName, [FromBody]string formModel)
    {
        var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
        var facultyID = await _facMapRepo.GetFacultyId(user.Id);
        try
        {
            TempFormStorage model = new TempFormStorage
            {
                UserId = facultyID,
                ParticipantActivityId = id,
                FormName = formName,
                JsonData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(formModel).ToString(),
                JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formModel),
                DateStored = DateTime.Now,
            };
            await _ctx.TempFormStorage.AddAsync(model);
            var result = await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

            if (!result)
            {

                return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = "" });
            }
            return Json(new { Status = "success", Message = "Data was saved" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "error", Message = ex });
        }
    }
```

The issue is when I do get this to send the data to the Action, it stores in in the database as a string and not a JsonString. If I bring the data as Json, the string formModel is always NULL.  Do I just continue to write an action for each form or is there a way to make this generic that I am missing?

Comment: One of my actions that currently works but is specific to the form looks like this:
        [Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{id?}/{formName?}/{formModel?}")]

        public async Task<ActionResult> InsertSPESHAMISAdd(int id, string formName, SPESHAMIS formModel)